Unable to get through level 0 members using @currmbr and @relative
I got struck with one of the requirement in Oracle Hyperion Essbase calculation script, I have one of the Entity member, and it has 15 children under it and all 15 children has hierarchies under them. Out of 15 children, 12 of the children has different percentages. So, based on these percentages I need to allocate data to its Level 0 members of each children. So, to get all the children of the Entity member, i used @children("Entity") in FIX statement. Then checking the condition if @currmbr("Entity") not equals to 0 or #missing. After this, I am trying to allocate data to the level 0 members using the function @Relative(@currmbr("Entity"),0) in FIX statement.
Here I have limitation to use @currmbr inside @relative function and in FIX statement. Without that statement I am unable to find a way to get through the level 0 members of each children to allocate data. I cannot hard code any on the children here as 12 children having percentages might increase to 15 or decrease below 12. Please help me the approach to get through this.
